# Getting string as ByteArray from phone data and changin it again to String

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working with data persistence in android and I'm trying to do a simple app where I save strings(like an agenda) so you can get them again even closing your app.

It is already working but the problem that I have is when I try to get my data back, changing ByteArray to String:

Saving the data:

```
fun saveShopData(newItem:String,context: Context){
    var file = 
    context.openFileOutput("shoppingList",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    file.write(newItem.toByteArray(charset = Charsets.US_ASCII))
    file.close()
}
```

Writing it and adding:

```
 var file = openFileInput("shoppingList")
 facade.addItem(file.read().toString())
 file.close()
```

The problem is that I get an Int when I use toString and not the strings that I used, probably because the BiteArray form. There's anything I can do to get the actual String?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way to translate InputStream to String is:

```
var file = openFileInput("shoppingList")
var inReader = BufferedReader(file.reader())
facade.addItem(inReader.readText())
```

1.Create a BufferedReader and pass a file.reader() that reads from your file.

2.Use BufferReader to use readText() and you get your desired String.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is InputStream, I think you can retrieve the text by following the examples here :)

https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-inputstream-to-string

Comment: [Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)